# How can I create all possible tree splits from X categorical features up to depth 3, in R?

Tags: r, recursion, tree, permutation

Assuming I have X categorical features, each with 2-5 distinct values.

For example 3 features with the following values -

```
f1 <- c('A', 'B')
f2 <- c('C', 'D', 'E')
f3 <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')
```

How can I create all possible "tree like" splits, up to 3 levels deep? the splits does not have to be binary and can be 3 / 4 way (or more) splits...

Based on my example here are some possible Trees -

1. (possible Tree example 1 branches)

- f1 == 'A'
- f1 == 'B'

2. 

- f1 =='A'
- f1 =='B' and f2 == 'C'
- f1 =='B' and f2 != 'C'

The splits in the tree can be based on different features on the same level as well, like so -

3.

- f3 == 'X' and f1 =='A'
- f3 == 'X' and f1 =='B'
- f3 <> 'X' and f2 =='C'
- f3 <> 'X' and f2 =='D'
- f3 <> 'X' and f2 =='E'

The output format can be in any form as long as the splits per tree can be understood.

I think some sort of recursion can be a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need recursion here. You can use `combn` and `expand.grid` to enumerate all possibilities. It's not clear from the question, but I assume that you want to include the possibility of nothing being selected at each level. In that case, we can represent an empty selection with `NA`. Then we can have the following function which shows all possible selections at each level:

```r
all_trees <- function(...) {
  sets <- lapply(list(...), function(x) {
    c(unlist(sapply(seq_along(x), function(y) {
      sapply(asplit(combn(x, y), 2), paste, collapse = "-")
    })), NA)})
  sets <- setNames(sets, paste0("level_", seq_along(sets)))
  do.call(expand.grid, sets)
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
f1 <- c('A', 'B')
f2 <- c('C', 'D', 'E')
f3 <- c('X', 'Y', 'Z')

all_trees(f1, f2, f3)
#>     level_1 level_2 level_3
#> 1         A       C       X
#> 2         B       C       X
#> 3       A-B       C       X
#> 4      <NA>       C       X
#> 5         A       D       X
#> 6         B       D       X
#> 7       A-B       D       X
#> 8      <NA>       D       X
#> 9         A       E       X
#> 10        B       E       X
#> 11      A-B       E       X
#> 12     <NA>       E       X
#> 13        A     C-D       X
#> 14        B     C-D       X
#> 15      A-B     C-D       X
#> 16     <NA>     C-D       X
#> 17        A     C-E       X
#> 18        B     C-E       X
#> 19      A-B     C-E       X
#> 20     <NA>     C-E       X
#> 21        A     D-E       X
#> 22        B     D-E       X
#> 23      A-B     D-E       X
#> 24     <NA>     D-E       X
#> 25        A   C-D-E       X
#> 26        B   C-D-E       X
#> 27      A-B   C-D-E       X
#> 28     <NA>   C-D-E       X
#> 29        A    <NA>       X
#> 30        B    <NA>       X
#> 31      A-B    <NA>       X
#> 32     <NA>    <NA>       X
#> 33        A       C       Y
#> 34        B       C       Y
#> 35      A-B       C       Y
#> 36     <NA>       C       Y
#> 37        A       D       Y
#> 38        B       D       Y
#> 39      A-B       D       Y
#> 40     <NA>       D       Y
#> 41        A       E       Y
#> 42        B       E       Y
#> 43      A-B       E       Y
#> 44     <NA>       E       Y
#> 45        A     C-D       Y
#> 46        B     C-D       Y
#> 47      A-B     C-D       Y
#> 48     <NA>     C-D       Y
#> 49        A     C-E       Y
#> 50        B     C-E       Y
#> 51      A-B     C-E       Y
#> 52     <NA>     C-E       Y
#> 53        A     D-E       Y
#> 54        B     D-E       Y
#> 55      A-B     D-E       Y
#> 56     <NA>     D-E       Y
#> 57        A   C-D-E       Y
#> 58        B   C-D-E       Y
#> 59      A-B   C-D-E       Y
#> 60     <NA>   C-D-E       Y
#> 61        A    <NA>       Y
#> 62        B    <NA>       Y
#> 63      A-B    <NA>       Y
#> 64     <NA>    <NA>       Y
#> 65        A       C       Z
#> 66        B       C       Z
#> 67      A-B       C       Z
#> 68     <NA>       C       Z
#> 69        A       D       Z
#> 70        B       D       Z
#> 71      A-B       D       Z
#> 72     <NA>       D       Z
#> 73        A       E       Z
#> 74        B       E       Z
#> 75      A-B       E       Z
#> 76     <NA>       E       Z
#> 77        A     C-D       Z
#> 78        B     C-D       Z
#> 79      A-B     C-D       Z
#> 80     <NA>     C-D       Z
#> 81        A     C-E       Z
#> 82        B     C-E       Z
#> 83      A-B     C-E       Z
#> 84     <NA>     C-E       Z
#> 85        A     D-E       Z
#> 86        B     D-E       Z
#> 87      A-B     D-E       Z
#> 88     <NA>     D-E       Z
#> 89        A   C-D-E       Z
#> 90        B   C-D-E       Z
#> 91      A-B   C-D-E       Z
#> 92     <NA>   C-D-E       Z
#> 93        A    <NA>       Z
#> 94        B    <NA>       Z
#> 95      A-B    <NA>       Z
#> 96     <NA>    <NA>       Z
#> 97        A       C     X-Y
#> 98        B       C     X-Y
#> 99      A-B       C     X-Y
#> 100    <NA>       C     X-Y
#> 101       A       D     X-Y
#> 102       B       D     X-Y
#> 103     A-B       D     X-Y
#> 104    <NA>       D     X-Y
#> 105       A       E     X-Y
#> 106       B       E     X-Y
#> 107     A-B       E     X-Y
#> 108    <NA>       E     X-Y
#> 109       A     C-D     X-Y
#> 110       B     C-D     X-Y
#> 111     A-B     C-D     X-Y
#> 112    <NA>     C-D     X-Y
#> 113       A     C-E     X-Y
#> 114       B     C-E     X-Y
#> 115     A-B     C-E     X-Y
#> 116    <NA>     C-E     X-Y
#> 117       A     D-E     X-Y
#> 118       B     D-E     X-Y
#> 119     A-B     D-E     X-Y
#> 120    <NA>     D-E     X-Y
#> 121       A   C-D-E     X-Y
#> 122       B   C-D-E     X-Y
#> 123     A-B   C-D-E     X-Y
#> 124    <NA>   C-D-E     X-Y
#> 125       A    <NA>     X-Y
#> 126       B    <NA>     X-Y
#> 127     A-B    <NA>     X-Y
#> 128    <NA>    <NA>     X-Y
#> 129       A       C     X-Z
#> 130       B       C     X-Z
#> 131     A-B       C     X-Z
#> 132    <NA>       C     X-Z
#> 133       A       D     X-Z
#> 134       B       D     X-Z
#> 135     A-B       D     X-Z
#> 136    <NA>       D     X-Z
#> 137       A       E     X-Z
#> 138       B       E     X-Z
#> 139     A-B       E     X-Z
#> 140    <NA>       E     X-Z
#> 141       A     C-D     X-Z
#> 142       B     C-D     X-Z
#> 143     A-B     C-D     X-Z
#> 144    <NA>     C-D     X-Z
#> 145       A     C-E     X-Z
#> 146       B     C-E     X-Z
#> 147     A-B     C-E     X-Z
#> 148    <NA>     C-E     X-Z
#> 149       A     D-E     X-Z
#> 150       B     D-E     X-Z
#> 151     A-B     D-E     X-Z
#> 152    <NA>     D-E     X-Z
#> 153       A   C-D-E     X-Z
#> 154       B   C-D-E     X-Z
#> 155     A-B   C-D-E     X-Z
#> 156    <NA>   C-D-E     X-Z
#> 157       A    <NA>     X-Z
#> 158       B    <NA>     X-Z
#> 159     A-B    <NA>     X-Z
#> 160    <NA>    <NA>     X-Z
#> 161       A       C     Y-Z
#> 162       B       C     Y-Z
#> 163     A-B       C     Y-Z
#> 164    <NA>       C     Y-Z
#> 165       A       D     Y-Z
#> 166       B       D     Y-Z
#> 167     A-B       D     Y-Z
#> 168    <NA>       D     Y-Z
#> 169       A       E     Y-Z
#> 170       B       E     Y-Z
#> 171     A-B       E     Y-Z
#> 172    <NA>       E     Y-Z
#> 173       A     C-D     Y-Z
#> 174       B     C-D     Y-Z
#> 175     A-B     C-D     Y-Z
#> 176    <NA>     C-D     Y-Z
#> 177       A     C-E     Y-Z
#> 178       B     C-E     Y-Z
#> 179     A-B     C-E     Y-Z
#> 180    <NA>     C-E     Y-Z
#> 181       A     D-E     Y-Z
#> 182       B     D-E     Y-Z
#> 183     A-B     D-E     Y-Z
#> 184    <NA>     D-E     Y-Z
#> 185       A   C-D-E     Y-Z
#> 186       B   C-D-E     Y-Z
#> 187     A-B   C-D-E     Y-Z
#> 188    <NA>   C-D-E     Y-Z
#> 189       A    <NA>     Y-Z
#> 190       B    <NA>     Y-Z
#> 191     A-B    <NA>     Y-Z
#> 192    <NA>    <NA>     Y-Z
#> 193       A       C   X-Y-Z
#> 194       B       C   X-Y-Z
#> 195     A-B       C   X-Y-Z
#> 196    <NA>       C   X-Y-Z
#> 197       A       D   X-Y-Z
#> 198       B       D   X-Y-Z
#> 199     A-B       D   X-Y-Z
#> 200    <NA>       D   X-Y-Z
#> 201       A       E   X-Y-Z
#> 202       B       E   X-Y-Z
#> 203     A-B       E   X-Y-Z
#> 204    <NA>       E   X-Y-Z
#> 205       A     C-D   X-Y-Z
#> 206       B     C-D   X-Y-Z
#> 207     A-B     C-D   X-Y-Z
#> 208    <NA>     C-D   X-Y-Z
#> 209       A     C-E   X-Y-Z
#> 210       B     C-E   X-Y-Z
#> 211     A-B     C-E   X-Y-Z
#> 212    <NA>     C-E   X-Y-Z
#> 213       A     D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 214       B     D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 215     A-B     D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 216    <NA>     D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 217       A   C-D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 218       B   C-D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 219     A-B   C-D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 220    <NA>   C-D-E   X-Y-Z
#> 221       A    <NA>   X-Y-Z
#> 222       B    <NA>   X-Y-Z
#> 223     A-B    <NA>   X-Y-Z
#> 224    <NA>    <NA>   X-Y-Z
#> 225       A       C    <NA>
#> 226       B       C    <NA>
#> 227     A-B       C    <NA>
#> 228    <NA>       C    <NA>
#> 229       A       D    <NA>
#> 230       B       D    <NA>
#> 231     A-B       D    <NA>
#> 232    <NA>       D    <NA>
#> 233       A       E    <NA>
#> 234       B       E    <NA>
#> 235     A-B       E    <NA>
#> 236    <NA>       E    <NA>
#> 237       A     C-D    <NA>
#> 238       B     C-D    <NA>
#> 239     A-B     C-D    <NA>
#> 240    <NA>     C-D    <NA>
#> 241       A     C-E    <NA>
#> 242       B     C-E    <NA>
#> 243     A-B     C-E    <NA>
#> 244    <NA>     C-E    <NA>
#> 245       A     D-E    <NA>
#> 246       B     D-E    <NA>
#> 247     A-B     D-E    <NA>
#> 248    <NA>     D-E    <NA>
#> 249       A   C-D-E    <NA>
#> 250       B   C-D-E    <NA>
#> 251     A-B   C-D-E    <NA>
#> 252    <NA>   C-D-E    <NA>
#> 253       A    <NA>    <NA>
#> 254       B    <NA>    <NA>
#> 255     A-B    <NA>    <NA>
#> 256    <NA>    <NA>    <NA>
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks, sounds in the right direction, I think this will give me all possible branches, but how can I split the results to trees? 

ideally, I would like to add a column with tree_number so that if I filter for tree_number == 4 for example I will get all branches for this tree

Comment: @user20966475 what would tree number 4 be? How are you defining a tree number?

Comment: tree_number 4 (or any other number) will include all rows that represent his branches.

In my initial question I gave an example of 3 trees, and for each tree all of his branches.